# tomcat jersey servlet initialization

Tags: tomcat, constructor, initialization, jersey

This is my first post on this forum. Apologies if I have violated any of the norms.

I am writing a RESTful servlet inside a Tomcat container and will connect to a database on startup (via JDBC) and then on receiving HTTP requests, it will insert the data in the HTTP POST request into the database.

I now know that the DB connection can be initialized in the contextInitialized method by implementing the ServletContextListener interface in the jersey webapp class.
However, I also have a constructor which keeps getting called for every HTTP post request. I just defined this constructor as I thought I might add some debug messages there to understand the flow.

Note that my web.xml has the load-on-startup parameter set to 1.

What I wanted to know are the following:
Why is Tomcat calling my webapp class constructor for every HTTP request directed towards my webservice ?
Also, in the logs of my webapp I noticed that the init method is getting called before the constructor. That sounds strange. Right ? or not really ?
But the init method is not called for each HTTP request for my webservice. It is only called when Tomcat starts-up.

My Tomcat version is v7.0 and I am using JDK 1.7.

Any help in understanding this behaviour will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're co-locating artifacts of different scopes in the same class, hence the weird behavior.

A ServletContextListener is expected to be an application-level scope, i.e. a Singleton if you will.

A Jersey resource class on the other hand is request-level scope, i.e. it gets created every time there's an incoming request to process.

I'd recommend to decouple those in two separate classes.